# problem with fourier font

Tags: fonts, bold, greek, fourier

i use fourier font for my math in my document but definitions, theorems,.. are not bold and when i write english names they are in bold (my text is in greek). Also i want to know what i have to do to change my math font as my text font thank you. Here is my code :

```
 \usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[active]{srcltx}
\usepackage{fourier}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Θεώρημα}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Λήμμα}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Πρόταση}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Πόρισμα}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Ορισμός}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Παρατήρηση}
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Αξίωμα}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Παράδειγμα}
\newtheorem{symb}[theorem]{Συμβολισμός}
\newtheorem{note}[theorem]{Σημείωση}





   \begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
\vert x+y\vert^2=...
\end{theorem}
\textlatin{Banach}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a full compilable code. Do you compile with `xelatex`?

Comment: @spyros you appear to have duplicate accounts.

Comment: The `srcltx` package is obsolete. The `fourier` font has no support for Greek, so you get font substitutions.

Comment: @user183722 It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 1):

In the log file you find

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LGR/futs/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `LGR/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 26.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LGR/futs/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `LGR/futs/m/n' instead on input line 27.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LGR/futs/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `LGR/futs/m/n' instead on input line 28.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LGR/futs/m/sl' undefined
(Font)              using `LGR/futs/m/n' instead on input line 31.
```

which is the explanation: `fourier` has no support for Greek (precisely, for the LGR encoding for Greek). Thus a fallback font is used and no choice of series or shape can be honored.

There is no Utopia based font available in TeX Live supporting Greek, I'm afraid.